# Analog and digital graph/

Tags: java, user-interface

I got three breakout boards form spark fun.
and i wanted to test them out.

something that i can visualize like a moving graph.

do you have any suggested links or anything I can reference?

suggestions are greatly appreciated!

. i just want to have something simple like a line just going across on a graph
similar to this to test them :)

[Best video codec to encode analog graph information / AVI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421628/best-video-codec-to-encode-analog-graph-information-avi)

Comment: What are the breakout boards?

Answer (score 0):

Umm, a graph of what exactly? I would suggest instead you grab a few LEDs and play with making them turn on/blink as your first project.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on which UI toolkit you are using (AWT, Swing, SWT). For SWT, you may want to look at [SWTChart](http://www.swtchart.org/).

I have also used [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) with good success.

Comment: Well Lets say I have data streaming out from an ez430 microcontroller.

Comment: and I want to graph that data instantly.